# Hash of a complete table

Tags: excel, vba, hash

The Excel macro I've created is checking the value of some tables for data coherence before running the actual code.
At first, the computation time was not perceptible, but my tables are getting bigger and bigger...
What I'm wanting to do, is checking the data coherence only if their contents were modified since last check. And I though of hash.

But, I was wondering if it's possible to create quickly a hash of an entire table? If I start to create a hash of each cells,  I'm afraid the computation time will be similar.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *"The Excel macro I've created"* There is no code in your question. • Note that calculating hashes takes more time the longer the data gets. So you run into the same issue. More data means more time.

Comment: Did you forget to post your code, or you are expecting a general answer not connected to your code solution? If yes, I am afraid that it is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is after every checking of the data coherence make a copy of that table into a hidden sheet (to freeze that state of data).

Next time you run your code you just compare your data against the hidden copy to check which data changed. Then you only need to check coherence of the changed data.

Comparings like this can be done quickly by reading both (data and hidden copy) into arrays and compare the arrays.

You can read a full range of data into an array with one singele line of code

```
Dim DataArray() As Variant
DataArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:C10").Value
```

`DataArray` is now an array containg the data of range A1:C10 and you can access it using:

```
DataArray(row, column)
```